# What is the typical size of a .dwg file?

Tags: saas, autocad, dwg

What is the typical size range of a .dwg file? I am developing a system to upload and download .dwg files.

Answer (score 1):

How large is a piece of paper?

You see, it all depends on the content. I have worked on 3d  cartographic maps that are 100mb or so.

2d polylines take less space than 3d polylines. There are many reasons why the file may be large. Another reason is when you have a lot of paper space layouts.

Also, old data is held with the file sometimes. So purging it can get rid of old unused references.

So the file size can vary from a few kb to a few mb  if not more.

Answer (score 0):

There is no typical file size, but it's not usual to have big files as most users will use xRef in such a case. You might consider also accept a .zip with all references on the package.